# How can I use WiX RegistrySearch to check for presence of a registry key?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Note that I'm not asking for a registry value. Just the key. How do I do that with WiX?

The following doesn't work when `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4` key exists:

```
<Property Id="VSTOINST1">
  <RegistrySearch Id="idVsto1" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4" Type="directory" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. You can get it from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56961">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (VSTOINST1)]]>
</Condition>
```

PS. For clarity I'm testing it on a 32-bit Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I create it in this way:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
...
<ComponentGroup Id="REGISTRYENTRIES" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="Registry" Guid="..." >
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\...\..." Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Name="Version" Value="[BuildVersioProp]" Type="string" />
                <RegistryValue Name="InstallSource" Value="[PATH]" Type="string" />
                <RegistryValue Name="Publisher" Value="Comapny" Type="string" />
            </RegistryKey >
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

Product:

```
<Product>
...
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature4" Title="CCC" Level="1" >
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="REGISTRYENTRIES" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

and add to property:

```
<Property Id="PATH"> 
    <RegistrySearch Id='my_app_dir' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\...\...' Name='InstallSource' />
</Property>
```